# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no sound on MacbookPro

Tags: 20.04

This method is not working:

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
> $ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
> $ mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/new_pulse_conf
> ```
>
> Reboot your PC.

[image: Screenshot of alsa-base.conf in nano]

Answer (score 4):

for everyone with macbook here you can find a solution to your problem by Compiling and installing driver:

**fedora package install:**

`dnf install wget make gcc kernel-devel`

**ubuntu package install:**

`apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic`

**arch package install:**

`pacman -S wget make gcc linux-headers`

**build driver:**

`git clone https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro.git`

`cd snd_hda_macbookpro/`

run the following command as root or with sudo:

`./install.cirrus.driver.sh`

`reboot`

Comment: This did not work for me in ubuntu 22.04, it used to work in 20.04 on the same HW.

Comment: @Otuken You might try again. I just tried on my MBP with 22.04 and it worked!

Comment: It worked. I need to install  third package mentioned by ubuntu itself when I tried to run the last command. Then it worked.

Comment: Where have you found this solution? mentioning the source could be very useful