# No sound on MacbookPro after kernel update in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, updates, 20.04, macbook-pro

I had a problem with my sound in ubuntu 20.04 and this fix [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no sound on MacbookPro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254124/ubuntu-20-04-lts-no-sound-on-macbookpro)
did work for me for a couple of months.

I updated my kernel to 5.4.0-48-generic (latest Ubuntu kernel), it cannot be compiled anymore and the solution does not work.

Errors linking are:

```
ERROR: "snd_hda_jack_detect_enable_callback" [/home/d/macBookPro/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda-5.4.0/snd-hda-codec-cirrus.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "snd_hda_jack_detect_state" [/home/d/macBookPro/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda-5.4.0/snd-hda-codec-cirrus.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "snd_hda_jack_tbl_get" [/home/d/macBookPro/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda-5.4.0/snd-hda-codec-cirrus.ko] undefined!
```

`uname -a` output reports the following:

```
Linux d-MacBookPro 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any hint appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I solved this by using previous kernel version `5.4.0-47-generic`. See [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140) to change it.