# Can't get sound on my Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, macbook

new to Ubuntu here and am running into an issue. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my 2016 Macbook Pro (Dual boot with OSX via rEFIt) and I get no sound. I have tried looking at alsamixer to make sure I'm not muted, I've tried pavucontrol which shows a bar in the "Output devices" tab, which moves up and down as if it's detecting sound, but there isn't anything in the speakers.

I tried this guide as well, but I either did something wrong or it just didn't work because it just gave me a bunch of empty, non-selectable fields in the audio mixer.

[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no sound on MacbookPro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254124/ubuntu-20-04-lts-no-sound-on-macbookpro)

I have since reinstalled Ubuntu and am sitting here fresh.

I'm really not sure what else to try. I'm a linux novice, trying to switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: Which MacBook Pro model are you using? Some models do not yet have reverse-engineered drivers available for the audio system.

Comment: It's a 2016 Macbook Pro. Model A1708. I'm not sure if this is the 13,1 or 14,1 model, but I saw a list which showed the sound worked on both of those, but I'm not sure what this list is.. https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux

Comment: There is [a reverse-engineered driver](https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro) for your Mac, but there are [quite](https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro/issues/23) a [few](https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro/issues/8) glaring [issues](https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro/issues/6) that remain unresolved 

Comment: Thank you. I also confirmed that this is the 14,1 model.

Do I just run these in order? First I do the package install for Ubuntu, then I do the steps for compile driver? These look identical to the steps I did the other day without success, but I may have done them incorrectly.