# Sound Macbook pro Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, macbook

Please could someone help here is my system information;

```
System:
  Host: lewis-host Kernel: 5.19.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro13,1 v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Apple model: Mac-473D31EABEB93F9B v: MacBookPro13,1
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Apple v: 499.40.2.0.0 date: 08/22/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Broadcom 720p FaceTime HD Camera driver: N/A
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-45-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I have no sound on my macbook pro that is running ubuntu please if you can point me in the direction for the correct driver thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us which model of Macbook Pro this is?

Comment: Early 2016 Macbook Pro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no sound on MacbookPro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254124/ubuntu-20-04-lts-no-sound-on-macbookpro)

Answer (score 0):

[The top answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254124/ubuntu-20-04-lts-no-sound-on-macbookpro) worked for me on a 2017 Macbook Pro (MacBookPro14,3) with Ubuntu 23.04.

- `apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic`
- `git clone https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro.git`
- `cd snd_hda_macbookpro/`
- `./install.cirrus.driver.sh`
- `reboot`

Microphone is working as well.

Comment: I encountered a problem when executing the last command mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/lib/modules/6.5.0-1009-apple-arm/updates’: Permission denied Please help