# No sound/Dummy output on a Ubuntu 22.04 Macbook pro

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, macbook, pipewire

I have tried to reinstalling pulseaudio and pipewire. It just won't work
:

```
~/Documents/Self$ sudo apt install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pulseaudio is already the newest version (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

:~/Documents/Self$ sudo apt install pipewire
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pipewire is already the newest version (1.0.0-1~ubuntu22.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have tried this as well

```
 :~$ pulseaudio --kill
 :~$ pulseaudio --start
```

nothing showed up even after reboot.

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service
```

What should I do now?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add details on what "won't work" means - no sound at all, crashing applications, error messages...?

Comment: No sound at all, but when I turn on the pc there’s sound indicating it’s turning on. Therefore the hardware should be good. Sorry for the confusions

Comment: If you need me to type in terminal, I’ll try to do it

Comment: To do a full reinstall and replace any missing files, you need to append your apt command as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/). So something like `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install pulseaudio pipewire`

Comment: Also: did you have sound in the past, like is this a new problem or has this problem been present since you first installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Also also, have you tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254159/)?

Comment: $ sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install pulseaudio pipewire
E: Option DPkg::Options::sudo: Configuration item specification must have an =<val>.

Comment: imma try to reinstall ubuntu

Comment: I have used a flash drive to reinstall Ubuntu. It still shows dummy output. Pain